# Redirect to url depending on device family

Tags: ios, swift, url, swift3

Im coding a app in Swift and I want to let it redirect to a different url depending on the device family

This is my `viewDidLoad` function:

> override func viewDidLoad() {
>       super.viewDidLoad()
>       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
>
> ```
> let device = Device()
> if device.isPod {
>     let lURL = URL(string: "http://myurl.com/ipod")
> } else if device.isPhone {
>     let lURL = URL(string: "http://myurl.com/iphone")
> } else if device.isPad {
>     let lURL = URL(string: "http://myurl.com/ipad")
> }
>
> let lURLRequest = URLRequest(url: lURL!)
> webView.loadRequest(lURLRequest)
>  }
> ```

When I run it it gives an error in `let lURLRequest = URLRequest(url: lURL!)`: "Use of unresolved identifier 'iURL'"

Im using [iDeviceKit](https://github.com/dennisweissmann/DeviceKit) to detect the device family

Comment: I have to wonder why you need 3 different URLs. Cannot the server detect the device type from user agent or simply from the screen bounds?